# Rails 3 / Form without Model: How do I create a form that is not tied to a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model, and I have a view that displays a form for creating a new object based on that model.  Let's call that form, `Form1`.

Once the user submits `Form1`, the object is created. I then want to display, on the following page, a second form `Form2`, which asks the user to check off various options before the object is saved to the database.

My problem is probably extremely basic. I don't know how to create `Form2`, given that it is not tied directly to the model. Because I am a `Rails` newbie, I have only created forms as following:

```
form_for(@object) { |f| ... }
```

*`@object` is an object instantiated from the model*

**Problem**: I do not believe that kind of code will work for my purposes here. How do I create `Form2`, given that it must not be based on `@object` or `@object`'s model?

**Some specifics from my app**:

The site accepts values (`Form1`) before redirecting to an `OAuth` server.

When the user verifies her credentials on the `OAuth` server, she is redirected back to my site. An `XML-RPC` request then retrieves information about the user's account on the `OAuth` server.

The `XML` response may indicate that the user has only one account on the `OAuth` server. If so, some values are retrieved from the `XML` and added to the object--which is then (finally) saved in the database--and the user is redirected to a success page.

However, if the `XML` response indicates that the user has multiple accounts on the `OAuth` server, I want to display a form (`Form2`) that allows the user to select which accounts on the OAuth server to associate with my site.  So `Form2` really asks the user *how many* objects to create, rather than about specific attributes of an object.

Comment: Use form_tag or other form helpers

Comment: Already solved on: http://stackoverflow.com/q/804313/428813, please look useful comment from Sarah

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Use `form_tag` instead of `form_for`, then use the appropriate form helpers: `text_field_tag` instead of `f.text_field`, `text_area_tag` instead of `f.text_area`, etc. Example:

```
<%= form_tag "/my_controller/update2" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag "account", "default info" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

The Rails API site has a great reference to all of the _tag helpers: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html

Answer (score 36):

Starting in rails3, validations have been decoupled from ActiveRecord so you can create vanilla objects that can be used as validators with the form helpers:

```
 class Person
   include ActiveModel::Validations

   attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name

   validates_each :first_name, :last_name do |record, attr, value|
     record.errors.add attr, 'starts with z.' if value.to_s[0] == ?z
   end
 end
```

and then in your template:

```
<%= form_for(Person.new) do |f| %>
...
```

It's a handy way to get the benefits of the form helpers for things like email forms without having to create a model object tied to your schema.

Answer (score 5):

To create a table-less model,

```
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name

  validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
end
```

Then in your view,

```
<%= form_for(Person.new) do |f| %>
 .... your form ....
<% end %>
```

Another similar solution can be found at `RailsCasts`:
[Active-Model](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model)

Comment: One has to [include ActiveModel::Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37822674/673826) as well and define `persisted?` to be false.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to use SimpleForm then there is a specific answer for that here [Does form_tag work with Simple_form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342277/does-form-tag-work-with-simple-form)