# Ruby on Rails: How to validate a model without Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, model

I'm currently trying to validate fields without having an `ActiveRecord::Base` inheritance.

My model stores the data on a cache server so I do not need ActiveRecord.

Anyway, I would like to validate the fields of the model like I would if I was using ActiveRecord (e.g `validates_numericality_of :quantity, :greater_than => 0`) ?

How can I do that?

Comment: I believe this is that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315850/rails-model-without-database

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Rails 3, Active Model contains the non-database functionality of Active Record.

Basically, you need to include `ActiveModel::Validations`, define your fields as `attr_accessor`, use an `initialize` method to initialize the attributes and make them non-persisted as your model isn’t persisted to a database.

This way you can have validations on the tableless model and your controller the same as if you were using Active Record. There's also a Railscast on this http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model.

Comment: [For Rails 4+ follow this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865821/rails-4-validate-model-without-a-database)

Answer (score 1):

Check out our [Veto gem](http://github.com/kodio/veto) instead if you're looking for a standalone validations for ruby objects. It's lightweight, and has no dependencies.. ActiveModel might be overkill.