# Validate a form using model and no table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I validate a form (such as a contact form) using a model that doesn't have a database table (so not standard record validation).

I've tried this, but I get the error: 
`undefined method`valid?' for Contact:Class`

```
class Contact
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :subject, :query
  validates :subject, { :presence => { message:'Please select a subject' } }
  validates :query, { :presence => { message:'Please enter your message' } }
  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end
  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

and then the methods:

```
def contact
  @page_title = 'Contact Us'
end

def contact_email
  if Contact.valid?
    message = "#{params[:subject]}: #{params[:query]}"
    current_user.send_contact_message(message)
    redirect_to '/contact', notice: 'Thank you for your message, we will be in touch shortly.'
  else
    render :contact
  end
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4 - Validate Model without a database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865821/rails-4-validate-model-without-a-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valid?` is an instance method. You can only call it on an instance of the class and not on a class. You need to change this line

```
if Contact.valid?
```

to this

```
contact = Contact.new(subject: 'some subject', query: 'some query')
if contact.valid?
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Tried that, and now I get the error `undefined method `valid?' for #<HomeController:0x007fa5b0186868>`

Comment: Oops sorry, didn't know that method was in a controller, you need to call it on contact object, check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

One the new features of Rails 4 was `ActiveModel::Model` which makes it extremely easy to create table-less models. It gives you validations, translations through the I18n module, form bindings, polymorphic routing etc. Pretty much everything `ActiveRecord::Base` does except persistence.

```
class Contact < ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :subject, :query
  validates :subject, presence: { message:'Please select a subject' }
  validates :query, presence: { message:'Please enter your message' }
end
```

Apart from that your error is caused by the fact that you are calling `.valid?` on the Contact class and not an instance.

The rails way would be to do:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]

# app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.valid?
      message = "#{params[:subject]}: #{params[:query]}"
      current_user.send_contact_message(message)
      redirect_to '/contact', notice: 'Thank you for your message, we will be in touch shortly.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private 

    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:foo, :bar)
    end
end
```