# Does form_tag work with Simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, simple-form

I have a form that is using `form_tag` and not sure how to use it with the [simple_form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form). This is how my form looks:

```
<%= form_tag create_multiple_prices_path, :method => :post do %>

  <% @prices.each_with_index do |price, index| %>
    <%= fields_for "prices[#{index}]", price do |up| %>
      <%= render "fields", :f => up %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= submit_tag "Done" %>
<% end %>
```

Can it be done? How would a `form_tag` change to use simple_form correctly? What about when using it with `fields_for`? A Newbie could use some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

simple_form is a wrapper around `form_for`, not `form_tag`. You can use `simple_form_for` instead of `form_for`, but `form_tag` just creates `<form>` tags with specified content, it is not relevant to simple form.

Answer (score 139):

You can use simple_form even if you aren't creating a form that's tied to a model.

Take this signin form as an example:

```
<%= simple_form_for :signin, { url: signin_path } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Sign In" %>
<% end %>
```

That will generate params like the following:

```
{
  ...
  "signin" => {
    "email"=>"test@test.com",
    "password"=>"[FILTERED]"},
    "commit"=>"Sign In"
   }
 }
```

In your controller you can reference the form fields using:

```
params[:signin][:email] ...
```

Comment: Check out Mauro Locatelli's answer to avoid embedded params.

Answer (score 7):

You can avoid use of

```
params[:signin][:email]
```

using

```
<%= f.input :email, input_html: { name: "email" } %>
```

so

```
params[:email]
```

Answer (score 1):

like @barelyknown said You can use simple_form even without model
You can also use `field_for` or `simple_field_for`

```
<%= simple_form_for :transaction_limits, {url: create_multiple_prices_path, method: :post} do |f| %>
  <% @prices.each_with_index do |price, index| %>
    <%= f.fields_for "prices[#{index}]", price do |up| %>
      <%= render "fields", :f => up %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "button" %>
<% end %>
```