# Remove route name from simple_form params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, simple-form

Simpleform seems to append the route name to its params hash. How can one prevent or remove it ?

```
simple_form_for @profile ...
```

returns params like:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "query"=>"" ...
```

But

```
simple_form_for profile_path
```

returns params like:

```
 params['people/search][:query]
```

I want to remove that people/search path but cannot figure out how by any means, anyone knows how to remove it and still use simple_form? thx!

Comment: The `*form_for` functions all expect models as their first arguments - giving it a string (`profile_path`) is confusing it.  If you have the target URL instead, you want `form_tag`, but I dunno if you can use `simple_form` with that - [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342277/does-form-tag-work-with-simple-form) implies that you can't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
  = simple_form_for  :people,  :url => request.fullpath, :method => :get,  :html => { :class => 'form-search' } do |f|
```