# How to use session_path with simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, simple-form

I'd like to adapt form_tag to simple_form

```
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
    <%= label_tag :password %>
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
<% end %>
```

it works fine, I can log in normally.

```
        <%= simple_form_for(sessions_path) do |f| %>
            <%= f.error_notification %>
            <%= f.input :password %>
            <%= f.button :submit %>
        <% end %>
```

Here I get 
    No route matches [POST] "/sessions/new"

In my routes.rb I have following line

```
get 'login', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new'
```

Could someone help me fix it?

Comment: are you using device for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

`form_for` (and therefore `simple_form_for`) assume that you have a model and are POSTing or PATCHing to its resource route.

But you don't have a model and that route is a GET route, so you need to pass in some options to simple_form to make it work.

This should do it:

`simple_form_for(sessions_path), method: :get`

But there's also this answer which should help (not the accepted one, the second one):

[Does form_tag work with Simple_form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342277/does-form-tag-work-with-simple-form)

Comment: When I use method: :get I'm redirected to sessions/new even if I enter correct password.

Comment: Actually, I think it should be a `POST` route. So rather than fixing the form, you should consider fixing your routes: `post 'login' => 'sessions#new'`